# How to prevent PrimeFaces editable DataTable from setting the updated value in a variable?

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I have these ajax listeners in my PrimeFaces (7.0) DataTable:

```
<p:ajax event="rowEditInit" listener="#{editKey.onRowEditInit(event, key)}"/>
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{editKey.onRowEdit(event, key)}"/>
```

I use `onRowEditInit` in my bean to save the row's initial value in `oldKey` when it is in edit mode, which works fine.

```
private KeyManagementKeys oldKey;

public void onRowEditInit(RowEditEvent event, KeyManagementKeys key) {
    oldKey = key;
}

public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event, KeyManagementKeys newkey) {
    keylistService.updateKey(newkey, oldKey);
}
```

The problem is that `oldKey` is then updated to the edited values when I edit the row in the UI. 
So by the time `onRowEdit` is called to complete the editing, `newKey` and `oldKey` have the same value.

How do I prevent this automatic value update of any variable with the same type as the DataTable values (`KeyManagementKeys`)? 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this (I don't know how is the KeyManagementKeys class, so code may needs some changes), to uncouple the two variables

```
public void onRowEditInit(RowEditEvent event, KeyManagementKeys key) {
    KeyManagementKeys oldKey = new KeyManagementKeys();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(oldKey, key);
}
```

Comment: thanks! After I set every single variable of ```oldKey``` when creating it as a new object to ```key```'s variables it worked and the variables uncoupled.